# Orbital-free DFT and Density Functional Tight-Binding: Comparison

Tags: density-functional-theory, reference-request, tight-binding, density-functional-tight-binding

There are many flavors of DFT that are alternative to, or go beyond the Kohn-Sham formulation (KS-DFT).
Some of these are based on approximations that sacrifice accuracy when compared to KS-DFT, but in exchange are computationally cheaper and allow the modeling of larger systems.

Two popular methods of this kind, are [Orbital-Free DFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital-free_density_functional_theory) (link to an answer on OFDFT [here](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/1513/what-are-the-types-of-dft)) and [Density Functional Tight-Binding](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/full/10.1098/rsta.2012.0483).

I have not yet seen a comparative study on the performance of these methods, but I wonder if anyone here is able to offer any insights about how they may compare?

Comment: +1. Someone asked me this question by email a few days ago. I'll try to write an answer when I have more time later. (I wrote the OFDFT answer you linked to.)

Comment: No way! Before I saw your answer, I was going to ask for a justification of OFDFT, (in similar spirit to this question, but you covered that. Seeing that however really reminded me of DFTB. Looking forward to that answer! :)

Comment: It's a good question. I should say that I'm not an expert on DFTB, so it will be good to hear from others too.

Comment: @wcw I thought of you the moment I saw this question's title! If you answer quickly it will become a hot network question 

Comment: @wcw as the question has now gone more than 1 month without an answer, would you consider to write something?

Comment: @wcw since it looks like this has had trouble getting answered, do you have a chance to answer it?

Comment: I am not an expert, but, searching, I found the following reference that compares some OFDFT functionals among them and with KSDFT: [DOI: 10.1021/acs.jctc.9b00183](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acs.jctc.9b00183).

Comment: Are you sure you want to compare these two directly? One is a tight-binding method…